# Toggle background color of same div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle the background color of same div.
It does changes once (from blue to red) as expected.
But it is not able to toggle back to red and continue toggling between the 2 colors. I know I should use "==" in the first if-statement but when using "==" not even the first toggle works.

Any suggestions how to get the toggle to work repetitive?

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("box");
  
  if (x.style.background == "blue") {
    x.style.background = "red";
  } else {
    x.style.background = "blue";
 }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box" onclick="toggleFunction()"></div>
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Comment: Yes thanks, I accepted your, I think it is a good solution. (even though it did not really explain why my original code could not work.)

Comment: You are using `=` in the comparison and not `==` that is why your code was not working.

Comment: It does not work, either with "==" nor "===".

Comment: check the edited snippet in this question. I have just replaced `==` and it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would to create a new class called `red` and toggle that using `classList.toggle`. The main advantage of this approach would be that you can toggle more `CSS` properties, if you use a class for toggling and this will also deduct the `if-else` comparison for you.

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("box");
  x.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box" onclick="toggleFunction()"></div>
```

Comment: @Hey24sheep appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".box" ).each(function() {
  $( this).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "red" );
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.box.red {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="box"></div>

<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```